# VS2015 SSRS rsInvalidReportDefinition when previewing report

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I'm frequently getting an rsInvalidReportDefinition error when previewing an SSRS report in VS2015 with SSDT, yet I can go back into Design mode change nothing hit Preview again and no error message.

Anyone else having this issue and found a potential workaround. I've logged this as an issue on Microsoft Connect:

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/2988044

Comment: Well did you go and check at the line where it shows the error. It might be that there may be some invalid character.